# array_values doesn't work with ArrayAccess object

Tags: php, arrayaccess

`array_values()` doesn't work with ArrayAccess object.
neither does `array_keys()`

why?

if I can access `$object['key']` I should be able to do all kind of array operations

Comment: array_keys($arrayaccessobject); ?

Comment: There is a comment http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php#104061 saying that array_key_exists() also does not work.

Comment: Can you extend your question and showing the full code of the $arrayaccessobject class?

Comment: Have you implemented a `function offsetGet()` which returns an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you've misunderstood the utility of ArrayAccess. It isn't just a sort of wrapper for an array. Yes, the standard example for implementing it uses a private `$array` variable whose functionality is wrapped by the class, but that isn't a particularly useful one. Often, you may as well just use an array.

One good example of ArrayAccess is when the script doesn't know what variables are available.

As a fairly silly example, imagine an object that worked with a remote server. Resources on that server can be read, updated and deleted using an API across a network. A programmer decides they want to wrap that functionality with array-like syntax, so `$foo['bar'] = 'foobar'` sets the `bar` resource on that server to `foobar` and `echo $foo['bar']` retrieves it. The script has no way of finding out what keys or values are present without trying all possible values.

So ArrayAccess allows the use of array syntax for setting, updating, retrieving or deleting from an object with array-like syntax: no more, no less.

Another interface, [`Countable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php), allows the use of `count()`. You could use both interfaces on the same class. Ideally, there would be more such interfaces, perhaps including those that can do `array_values` or `array_keys`, but currently they don't exist.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayAccess` is very limited. It does not allow the use of native `array_` functions (no existing interface does).

If you need to do more array-like operations on your object, then you are essentially creating a collection. A collection should be manipulated by its methods.

So, create an object and extend [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php). This implements `IteratorAggregate`, `Traversable`, `ArrayAccess`, `Serializable` and `Countable`.

If you need the keys, simply add an `array_keys` method:

```
public function array_keys($search_value = null, $strict = false)
{
    return call_user_func_array('array_keys', array($this->getArrayCopy(), $search_value, $strict));
}
```

Then you can:

```
foreach ($object->array_keys() as $key) {
    echo $object[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)/[`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) allows objects to work as arrays, but they're still objects. So instead of [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) (which work only on arrays) you should use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/get_object_vars), for example:

```
var_dump(array_keys(get_object_vars($ArrObj)));
```

or convert your ArrayObject by casting it into array by `(array) $ArrObj`, e.g.:

```
var_dump(array_keys((array)$ArrObj));
```